# Is AJAX Necessary for Returning a PHP Response?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

On my index.php I have a form that posts to  a file submit.php.  Submit.php sanatizes the data and submits it to a mySQL database and echos:

```
<h1>Message Sent</h1>
<p>Thanks for contacting us.  Will get back to you shortly</p>
```

Which I can see in my console under response.  I would like to put the response on my page, but am unsure how to do this.  Reading through other stackoverflow posts, it looks like I'll need to use AJAX to check if the users form has been submitted (not sure what the SQL query would look like for this), then if it has been submitted return the above HTML.

The thing is I'm not wanting to GET any of the data from the form, I'm just wanting to check if the form was submitted successfully to the database.  Would I need to do a AJAX request to the database to see if it was or could I somehow grab the console response and put it on the page?

If I did need to use AJAX, what would I want to GET?  The form includes their first name, last name, email, phone, website, and description.  I'm unsure what I would want to use GET since I don't want their information being processed unsecured as a GET request (my understanding is that GET requests shouldn't contain information that needs to be secure).

Also, I'm assuming that I could determine when the php HTML response was returned use something like the following code from the W3:

```
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
```

To sum it up:

- How can I get a PHP's POST response on my page?
- If using AJAX what would I want to GET since I don't need to return any of the data?
- Would I use code similar to the above to determine when the post was completed?

EDIT:

Below is the form:

```
<div id="contact-box">
    <div id="container">
        <form class="well form-horizontal" action="/submit.php " method="post"  id="contact_form">
    <fieldset>

    <!-- Form Name -->
    <legend>Contact Us Today!</legend>

    <!-- Text input-->

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label">First Name</label>
      <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
      <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
      <input  name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control"  type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Text input-->

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" >Last Name</label>
        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
        <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i></span>
      <input name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control"  type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Text input-->
           <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail</label>
        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i></span>
      <input name="email" placeholder="E-Mail Address" class="form-control"  type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Text input-->

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Phone #</label>
        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i></span>
      <input name="phone" placeholder="(845)555-1212" class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Website or Domain Name</label>
       <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-globe"></i></span>
      <input name="website" placeholder="Website or Domain name" class="form-control" type="text">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Text area -->

    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Project Description</label>
        <div class="col-md-4 inputGroupContainer">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i></span>
                <textarea class="form-control" name="comment" placeholder="Project Description"></textarea>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <p class="antispam"><input type="text" name="url" /></p>


    <!-- radio checks -->
     <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Do you Have Hosting?</label>
                            <div class="col-md-4">
                                <div class="radio">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="radio" name="hosting" value="yes" /> Yes
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                                <div class="radio">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="radio" name="hosting" value="no" /> No
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>


    <!-- Button -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning" >Send <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span></button>
      </div>
    </div>

    </fieldset>
    </form>
    </div>
        </div><!-- /.container -->
</div>
```

Comment: If you are submitting a form to `Submit.php` and you want that page to output a response, you can just echo the response, no need to do an additional ajax call to check the status. You can check all the status on the page that does the insert or just assume that if there were no errors, it processed correctly. In this case, ajax is used if you want to submit the form to `Submit.php` without reloading the page, then you would use ajax and can get and show the response.

Comment: Right now, when I click submit button on the index.php page the page doesn't change.  The only way that I can tell that the response is successful is by checking the console. where it shows me:

POST http://nameofurl/submit.php 200 195ms or something similar.   

Should the default behavior of a POST be causing the page to reload?

Comment: Can you show your form?

Comment: @JakeN, Just added it.

Comment: @strasbal — Given that form, since there doesn't appear to be any JavaScript associated with it, the page should be replaced with the output of `/submit.php` (unless that output is a No Content status, which doesn't sound likely).

Comment: @strasbal — If the HTML that you say is appearing on the console really is doing that, then you must have some JavaScript which is preventing the normal submission of the form, making an Ajax request, and then outputting the result to the content.

Comment: @Quentin, just found that code.  I used a form I found online and had added the script that came along with it.  Editing the script solved the issue.